# Preservence of CPD (conditionally positive definiteness) under infinite integral

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, improper-integrals, inner-products

Let $A = [a_{ij}(t)]$ be any $n$-by-$n$ square matrix function defined for $t>0$, and $B =[b_{ij}]$, where $$b_{ij} = \int_0^\infty \,a_{ij}(t)\,\text{d}t\,.$$
An $n$-by-$n$ matrix $M$ is said to be *conditionally positive definite* or *CPD* if $\langle x, Mx\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $x_{1}+x_{2}+.......+x_{n}=0$.
Then prove that $B$ is CPD, if $A(t)$ is CPD for every $t\in (0,\infty)$."

Any help! I know I need to use inner product definition here, but the integral sign is bothering me. Any suggestion or tip will be really helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $B$ a matrix space as well?

Comment: No idea. I give an example to explain my question. Let $A = [t^{i+j}]$ be a CPD matrix for every $t \in (0,\infty)$. Then what can you say about B for any t.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A(t)=\begin{bmatrix}a_{i,j}(t)\end{bmatrix}_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$ is a CPD (Chicago Police Department?) matrix for each $t\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.  Let $x:=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$ be such that $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=0$.  Then
$$\big\langle x,A(t)\,x\big\rangle\geq 0\,.\tag{*}$$

Observe that
$$ \langle x,B\,x\rangle =\Biggl\langle x,\left(\int_0^\infty\,A(t)\,\text{d}t\right)\,x\Biggr\rangle\,,$$
where the integral of a matrix function is done entrywise.  By linearity of the inner product and of the integral operator, we see that
$$ \langle x,B\,x\rangle =\int_0^\infty\,\big\langle x,A(t)\,x\big\rangle\,\text{d}t\,.$$
From (*), we conclude that $\langle x,B\,x\rangle \geq 0$, whence $B$ is also a Chicaco police officer.